# Encrypt/ Secure communication Android app <-> REST webservice

Tags: java, android, rest, encryption

I want to create a backend for my android app with Tapestry5 and this http://code.google.com/p/t5-restful-webservices/ plugin. 
The app will communicate with the server by calling REST methods both for registered users (that would be easy to secure I guess) as well as unregistered users. 
Now of course I don't want people to just call that webservice from a browser.

How can I make sure that only my app can make calls to this backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 approaches:

Use SSL to secure the connection. SSL can do a handshake checking the credentials.
To authenticate the user you can use a certificate or a PSK.

Or you can simply create a Hash (SHA or MD5) of your data and include a key. This is called hmac. A reverse engineer may get the Key cause you have to hardcode it in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! With both methods, people would not be able to recreate a call to the webservice from their browsers or there own android code, because they don't know the (encrypted) key that I'm sending from my app?

Comment: Exactly. But as it is hardcoded it may be retrieved by Reverse Engineering. The Key is never send as it only used to create the hash

Answer (score 1):

checking for the users UA  could help...

Comment: Isn't it pretty easy to spoof?